# Intelligently altering URL's

Tags: hooks, uri

I have a dilemma.

For my articles content type, i'm wondering how to alter a url automatically if i need to replace the hyperlink of my image thumbnails residing on my site to link to my other site which is my data repository on another server. Apart from doing it manually, i would like to know if i could automate this and create a script to do it, but i'm also not sure where to put it.

regards,
V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe one of the better solutions to this would involve an extension to [Storage API](http://drupal.org/project/storage_api). You can't do it out of the box since it your own server, instead of say S3, but it seems like the best fit. When I saw a demo presentation by the maintainer, he showed how one could split thumbnails storage to a low-redundancy system from base image storage, which was stored more safely.

Comment: Cool, this is awesome, i'll try it out now. Thanks Letharion. :)